# Cannot get ASP.NET MVC client side validation working

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation

I have in the fact copied the code of Login page in the ASP.NET MVC application template (provided with VS). In the original template, client side validation is working but when I copy all the connected code I get only server side validation (no red fields, post back even if data are incorrect).

Here is my model code:

```
public class LogOnModel {
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "User name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Remember me?")]
    public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the controller:

```
public class LogOnController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index() {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(LogOnModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid) {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Games");
        }

        return View(model);
    }
}
```

And this is the View:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<PuzzleHunter.Web.Models.LogOnModel>" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/SiteMasterPage.master" %>
<asp:Content runat="server" ID="Content" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">

<script src="<%: Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<%: Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>

<% using (Html.BeginForm()) { %>
    <%: Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Login was unsuccessful. Please correct the errors and try again.") %>
    <div>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Account Information</legend>
            <div class="editor-label">
                <%: Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName) %>
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                <%: Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName) %>
                <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName) %>
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                <%: Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password) %>
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                <%: Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password) %>
                <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password) %>
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                <%: Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe) %>
                <%: Html.LabelFor(m => m.RememberMe) %>
            </div>
            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Log On" />
            </p>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
<% } %>
```

I also have following lines in my `Web.config` file:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
</appSettings>
```

---

### Edit

I include here the output html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">


<head id="Head1"><title>
    Šifrovačky  

    </title><link href="Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="content">


    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <form action="/Logon" method="post">
        <div>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Account Information</legend>

                <div class="editor-label">
                    <label for="UserName">User name</label>
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    <input data-val="true" data-val-required="The User name field is required." id="UserName" name="UserName" type="text" value="" />
                    <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="UserName" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                </div>

                <div class="editor-label">
                    <label for="Password">Password</label>
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    <input data-val="true" data-val-required="The Password field is required." id="Password" name="Password" type="password" />
                    <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Password" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                </div>

                <div class="editor-label">
                    <input data-val="true" data-val-required="The Remember me? field is required." id="RememberMe" name="RememberMe" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="RememberMe" type="hidden" value="false" />
                    <label for="RememberMe">Remember me?</label>
                </div>

                <p>
                    <input type="submit" value="Log On" />
                </p>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    </form>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

For comparison this is the output of VS MVC template where client side validation is working:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head><title>

        Log On
        </title><link href="../Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="page">

            <div id="main">
        <script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <form action="/Account/LogOn" method="post">
            <div>
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Account Information</legend>

                    <div class="editor-label">
                        <label for="UserName">User name</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="editor-field">
                        <input data-val="true" data-val-required="The User name field is required." id="UserName" name="UserName" type="text" value="" />
                        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="UserName" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="editor-label">
                        <label for="Password">Password</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="editor-field">
                        <input data-val="true" data-val-required="The Password field is required." id="Password" name="Password" type="password" />
                        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Password" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="editor-label">
                        <input data-val="true" data-val-required="The Remember me? field is required." id="RememberMe" name="RememberMe" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="RememberMe" type="hidden" value="false" />
                        <label for="RememberMe">Remember me?</label>
                    </div>

                    <p>
                        <input type="submit" value="Log On" />
                    </p>
                </fieldset>
            </div>
        </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Do you wish to exclude PropertyErrors or not. The argument to ValidationSummary needs to be set false then

Comment: @HelloWorld First I want client side validation to take place. Then I may think about other PropertyErrors. I have a feeling that this is caused by something really simple and stupid.

Comment: Is there something in `Web.config` that may cause client validation to not to work ?

Comment: Have you included jQuery as well in your script includes? You may want to use Firebug and see if there are any errors in your browser console as well.

Comment: @HelloWorld I don't know what you mean by "skrip includes" but if you mean this: `<script src="<%: Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>` it is inside my master page's header tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the following *before* the `FORM` begins:

```
<% Html.EnableClientValidation();%>
```

Also, ensure you have this script referenced:

```
<script src="<%=Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcJQueryValidation.js")%>"
```

As well as jQuery itself.

Comment: No this is not the problem. When add that line, it is still not doing any client side validation. I have Validation summary there anyway - line 8. And it is on the same place as in the template provided by VS.

Comment: Adding `<script src="<%: Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcJQueryValidation.js")%>" type="text/javascript"></script>` (what is your answer has bad syntax)
and `<% Html.EnableClientValidation();%>` did not make any difference.  Note: the code of the view and model is exactly the same as code of view and model in VS template. Template DOES client-side validation. So I guess problem is somewhere else. I don't understand what you meant by "reference jQuery itself" but I have checked my libraries and they include all libraries that are also in template project.

Comment: pleaase see my edit: I have added the html output of the page so you can find exactly what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: `<script src="<%: Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>` was not in my Master page header tag at first. When I added it it should work but it did not for next 4 hours.

Probably because Firefox kept showing me the old version with no reference to  `<script src="<%: Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>`. Or...
Accept goes to the only answer that is not mine there.